# Creating string with formated string number within it

Tags: swift

I am trying to add text to the beginning of a value that is number formatted. I have tried a few options but no luck. Here is what I have so far:

```
calculationLabel.text = "IRD Penalty: \(format: "$%.02f", penalty)"
```

it returns `"IRD Penalty: format: "$%.02f", result"`

Thoughts?

Comment: Use NSString(format: string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format` is only available with a `String` initializer, not with `String` interpolation.  Also make sure you have `import Foundation` (or `import UIKit` or `import Cocoa`) in your file.

Here are three ways to do it in one line:

1. Put your leading `String` into the format `String`:

   ```
   calculationLabel.text = String(format: "IRD Penalty: $%.02f", penalty)
   ```
2. Use `+` to concatenate the leading `String` with the formatted `String`:

   ```
   calculationLabel.text = "IRD Penalty: " + String(format: "$%.02f", penalty)
   ```
3. Put the full `String(format:)` call inside of the `String` interpolation:

   ```
   calculationLabel.text = "IRD Penalty: \(String(format: "$%.02f", penalty))"
   ```

Comment: Kevin, you're posting the comments on the wrong answer.  Make sure you are calling `String(format...)` when using `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be archived by:

```
let my_format = String(format:"%.02f", penalty)
calculationLabel.text = "IRD Penalty: \(my_format)"
```

If you don't feel comfortable doing that every times, you can extends class.

```
extension Double {
    func my_format() -> String {
        return String(format: "%.02f", self)
    }
}

calculationLabel.text = "IRD Penalty: \(penalty.my_format())"
```

I haven't test the code. But that should be enough the get an idea.

Comment: Thank you. The "+" is giving an error cannot be applied to type String and (format: string double).